# How to stop Jquery countTo from refreshing everytime page is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrolltop

I'm trying to use the Jquery countTo plugin with some additional script that runs when my viewport gets to a certain point on the webpage. Everything works smoothly except for the fact that the `countTo` animation continuously runs when I scroll through the page even after the animation has faded in and finished.

Here's the code.

```
/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1000);
            jQuery(function($) {
                $('.timer').countTo({
                    from: 1500,
                    to: 3928,
                    speed: 3000,
                    refreshInterval: 50,
                    onComplete: function(value) {
                        console.debug(this);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }); 

});
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.timer3').countTo({
    from: 10,
    to: 784,
    speed: 3000,
    refreshInterval: 50,
    onComplete: function(value) {
        console.debug(this);
    }
}, {triggerOnce: true});
```

triggerOnce:true, allows it to execute only once.

Answer (score 0):

I will put this here just in case someone still finds it helpful 
This is for the jquery-countTo https://github.com/mhuggins/jquery-countTo

we need to calculate the position to check if the element "myelement" is shown, and do something about it.

In this case we calculate the positon to see if we have reached the element yet, then call the method and flag it off by setting "eventFired" to true;

Html:

```
<div id="myelement">
    <span class="timer" data-from="0" data-to="75" 
         data-speed="500" data-refresh-interval="1">
    </span>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
var eventFired = false,
objectPositionTop = $('#myelement').offset().top;
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
var currentPosition = $(document).scrollTop()+100;

if (currentPosition >= objectPositionTop && eventFired === false) {
    eventFired = true;
    $('.timer').countTo();
  }
});
```

This will successfully execute counters only once when the element "myelement" is visited.